# How to change pepper text to speech speed in an android module?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, text-to-speech, pepper

I had been working on developing an android application in the pepper robot using Softbank pepper SDK. I want to change the text to speech speed of the pepper robot. I tried looking different their class packages but I could not find how to set speed before pepper could say something.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a number of tags in the text to modify Pepper's text to speech output. There is a list of them [here](https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/pepper-naoqi-25/naoqi-developer-guide/naoqi-apis/naoqi-audio/altexttospeech/altexttospeech-tutorial#-using-tags-for-voice-tuning-). In this case, you want to use the `rspd` tag. For normal speed, use `\\rspd=100\\`, for slower choose a value down to 50, or for faster, up to 400.

For the purposes of this I'll modify the QiSDK Say example in java from [here](https://qisdk.softbankrobotics.com/sdk/doc/pepper-sdk/ch4_api/conversation/reference/say.html#say), but the same applies to kotlin.

```java
// Create a phrase.
Phrase phrase = new Phrase("\\rspd=70\\ This is slow \\rspd=200\\ and this is fast!");

// Build the action.
Say say = SayBuilder.with(qiContext)
                    .withPhrase(phrase)
                    .build();

// Run the action synchronously.
say.run();
```

Changing the speed might make the speech sound funny. You can compensate by changing the pitch too.

```java
Phrase phrase = new Phrase("\\rspd=70\\ \\vct=120\\ This is slow.");
```

You can experiment with the other tags to get almost any effect you want.

Comment: Are there any ways to set once instead of per phrase?

Comment: Unfortunately not with the Android QiSDK APIs, no. But you could write a function that wraps the say functionality and applies the speed tag to every phrase. Would that suffice for your use case?

Comment: Yes. I will do the same. Thanks for your help

Answer (score -1):

You can modify the speed using: `tts.setParameter("speed", value)`

ex:

```
self.proxy_tts.post.setParameter("speed", 80)
    self.proxy_tts.post.say(say)
    self.proxy_animation_player.runTag("hello")
```

Speed value range: [50-400]

[Modify speed](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/naoqi/audio/altexttospeech-tuto.html#tag-tutorial)
[Speed value range](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-4/naoqi/audio/altexttospeech-api.html#ALTextToSpeechProxy::setParameter__ssCR.floatCR)

Comment: This works in the Choregraphe version of Pepper, but this questions is asking about Android Pepper which doesn't have this functionality implemented yet.

Comment: This solution I know it and it works with Naoqi 2.5. My question was about the android module.